# How to fetch only "project Id" from database onto a Pop-up form for only those projects selected by user?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, popup

I am using MySQL Database under which I have a table named sponsors having following columns

```
id | project_id | project_name | sector | duration | budget | location
```

Now, I have created a page in php on which a user can select multiple projects at a time by clicking on the checkbox as you can see in the image below :
[table with checkboxs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrGMA.png)

After selecting the projects, when user clicks on submit, a pop-up form will appear like this :
[popup form for fetching "project_id"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqj3p.png)

On which there should be the comma separated values of project_id (from the Database) of all the selected projects by user.

So far I've done this much coding

for **checkbox**(in database table)

```
<td> <input type="checkbox" name="check_id[]"
value="<?php $row["project_id"];?>"> </td>
<td> <?php echo $data["project_id"]; ?>   </td>
<td> <?php echo $data["project_name"]; ?> </td>
```

for popup form input field to fetch only **project_id**

```
 <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right"  for="orangeForm- 
  name">Project Id</label>
 <input type="text" id="orangeForm-name" name="Project_id" class="form-control validate">
```

[see this](https://www.paste.org/92566) to have a view of full code.

So, my question is **How to fetch only project_id values from database onto a Pop-up form for only those projects that have been checkbox selected by user ?**

Answer (score 0):

Don't take the project_id again from the database. Just insert the comma separated project_ids into the pop up text field where you want them using jquery whenever user check or uncheck a project.

**Refer :**

> $(".classofcheckboxes input:checkbox").on('change',function()  {
>   if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
>         // update your comma separated project_id string directly of pop up field.  });